# change a letter in variable while iterating through for loop

Tags: bash, shell

i have a variable $x having a sample values like isd21anms.com, isd31anms.com etc. Now i want to iterate through for loop to change the no 1 from 1 through 1,2,3 4. Please look below code

```
for i in 1 2 3 4
do
     change $i such that I get values isd21anms.com, isd22anms.com, isd23anms.com, isd24anms.com
done
```

remember $x can have values like isd21anms.com, isd31anms.com, isd41anms.com. So i have to save it in variable and apply for loop on it instead of using a constant value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in 1 2 3 4
do
y=`echo $temp | sed "s/\(.*\).\(anms.com\)/\1"${i}"\2/g"`
echo "y is $y"
done
```

tested below:

```
> ./temp.sh
y is isd21anms.com
y is isd22anms.com
y is isd23anms.com
y is isd24anms.com
> setenv temp "isd31anms.com"
> ./temp.sh
y is isd31anms.com
y is isd32anms.com
y is isd33anms.com
y is isd34anms.com
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use brace expansion for this

```
for i in isd{1..4}{1..4}anms.com; do
  echo $i
done
```

output:

```
    isd11anms.com
    isd12anms.com
    isd13anms.com
    isd14anms.com
    isd21anms.com
    isd22anms.com
    isd23anms.com
    isd24anms.com
    isd31anms.com
    isd32anms.com
    isd33anms.com
    isd34anms.com
    isd41anms.com
    isd42anms.com
    isd43anms.com
    isd44anms.com
```

[brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly:

```
for x in isd21anms.com isd31anms.com isd41anms.com
do
        for i in {1..4}
        do
                y=${x/1/$i}
                echo $y
        done
done
```

On running this, got:

```
isd21anms.com
isd22anms.com
isd23anms.com
isd24anms.com
isd31anms.com
isd32anms.com
............
```

Comment: $x can have values like isd21anms.com, isd31anms.com, isd41anms.com.so your solution will fail in that case coz ur considering only one case isd21.... and not isd31, isd41 and so on.

Comment: see, I have a variable to use here it may have any value out of isd11anms.com isd21anms.com isd31anms.com isd41anms.com  when i run the script. so i don't know which valu it will take when i run. i will have  to use this variable and iterate.

Comment: so if my variable is suppose isd31anms.com , then i should get values such as isd31anms.com, isd32anms.com, isd33anms.com, isd34anms.com.